# How to read extension values like key info and key signature with OID

Tags: go

```
var cert *x509.Certificate
cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(myCertificate)
```

From this I need to retrieve extension values in bytes. I have the OID to be used for that. I am able to find code for adding extensions to a certificate. But not retrieving it. Can anyone share a sample code on how to do that?

Update:

Now, I am able to get the extensions

```
var extensions []pkix.Extension
var cert *x509.Certificate
byteValue, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(myCert)
cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(byteValue)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error in parsing certificate")
}
extensions = cert.Extensions
checkId := []int{2, 5, 6, 135, 3, 2, 41}
for _, ext := range extensions {
    if reflect.DeepEqual(ext.Id, checkId) {
        fmt.Println("true")
    }
}
```

}

But the deep equal return false (the particular oid is present), I need to retrieve the value of that particular extension. Can anyone suggest some steps to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reflect.DeepEqual does not work because the types are different. The normal way to check OIDs is using the [asn1.ObjectIdentifier](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/asn1/#ObjectIdentifier) as follows:

```
checkID := asn1.ObjectIdentifier{2, 5, 6, 135, 3, 2, 41}
for _, ext := range extensions {
    if ext.Id.Equal(checkId) {
        fmt.Println("true")
    }
}
```

If it isn't there, don't forget to check `ExtraExtensions`.